# The module doesn't work and just redirect me 404

Tags: magento-1.9

The module allows me to export the orders according to the grid I assigned, but here's the thing everything works fine but the moment I click submit to export the orders it just gives me 404, so I believe the issue is related to the router somehow, and I'm having lack of knowledge in this regard, I would appreciate any hint or guidance in this regard.

**=> config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<config>
    <modules>
        <newmodule_ExportOrders>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </newmodule_ExportOrders>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <exportorders before="Mage_Adminhtml">newmodule_ExportOrders_Adminhtml</exportorders>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportorders>
                <class>>newmodule_ExportOrders_Helper</class>
            </exportorders>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <exportorders>
                <class>>newmodule_ExportOrders_Block</class>
            </exportorders>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
            <events>
                <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                        <observers>
                            <newmodule_ExportOrders_Model_Observer>
                                <type>singleton</type>
                                <class>newmodule_ExportOrders_Model_Observer</class>
                                <method>addMassAction</method>
                            </newmodule_ExportOrders_Model_Observer>
                        </observers>
                </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**=> controllers :**

```
<?php

class newmodule_ExportOrders_Adminhtml_ExportOrders_ExporterController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function exportshipmentAction(){
        $fileName = 'orders_shipments.csv';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('exportorders/adminhtml_sales_order_gridsda');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());

    public function exportsdashipmentsAction()
    {
        $fileName = 'orders_sda_shipments.csv';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('exportorders/adminhtml_sales_order_gridnew');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    }
}
```

**=> observer :**

```
    <?php
class newmodule_ExportOrders_Model_Observer
{
    public function addMassAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addItem('exportorders_bartolini', array(
                'label' => 'Export Shipment Bartolini',
                'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('adminhtml/exportorders_exporter/exportshipment'),
            ));
            $block->addItem('exportorders_sda', array(
                'label' => 'Sda Shipment Bartolini',
                'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('adminhtml/exportorders_exporter/exportsdashipment'),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm your module is enable ?

Comment: Is it necessary to override `Mage_Adminhtml` module for your module?

Comment: The module is enabled, what do you mean to override mage_adminhtml?

Comment: as per your code in `config.xml` you have overidden core `Mage_Adminhtml`  module, What is the purpose of doing this ?

Comment: I'm trying to use my controller, as you can see I want to point the mass actions to right grid so it exports the orders accordingly.

Comment: I just want to make sure that your module is not to extend any core functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as @Dinesh suggested you have to capitalise your namespace and module

As you are not extending any core functionality , You can change your router code to below-

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <exportorders>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Newmodule_ExportOrders</module>
                <frontName>exportorders</frontName>
            </args>
        </exportorders>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

After that you can get your adminhtml url as below

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('exportorders/exportorders_exporter/exportshipment', array('_secure' => true);

Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('exportorders/exportorders_exporter/exportsdashipments', array('_secure' => true);
```

Also Make Sure that your controller file's path should be-

> app/code/your_codePool/Newmodule/ExportOrders/controllers/Adminhtml/ExportOrders/ExporterController.php

**Update**

As per your comment below for SUPEE-6788, in your router code in `config.xml` try changing

```
<exportorders before="Mage_Adminhtml">newmodule_ExportOrders_Adminhtml</exportorders>
```

to

```
<newmodule_exportOrders after="Mage_Adminhtml">Newmodule_ExportOrders_Adminhtml</newmodule_exportOrders>
```

Comment: But this won't work, as you know SUPEE 6788 changed the way the routers work.

Comment: Okay, leave the config.xml code and try changing the urls as per my answer

Comment: Are you sure it won't work? As I am using Magento 1.9.3.4 (includes SUPEE-6788) and this code works pretty fine in it.

Comment: https://www.domain.com/index.php/exportorders/exportorders_exporter/exportshipment/ This gives 404

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

First letter of your Namespace and Module must be capital. So you have to change this first of all.

Now create your admin router as below in **config.xml** file

```
<config>
....
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Newmodule_ExportOrders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Newmodule_ExportOrders_Adminhtml</Newmodule_ExportOrders>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
....    
</config>
```

Then call your controller action as below

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/exportorders_exporter/exportshipment', array('_secure' => true);

Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/exportorders_exporter/exportsdashipments', array('_secure' => true);
```

Comment: is the portion "</Newmodule_ExportOrders>" should be the same as the module name? or I can simply name as I want because according to Magento documentation this has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: This is a conventional way so I suggest you to let it be as it is.

Comment: I just tried it, and I got 404

Comment: Have you capitalize your namespace and module name ? change it in every file and folder name. It should work.

Comment: I did, that's why I'm confused myself :(

Answer (score 0):

Please do like a Magento standard.

**app/code/local/Newmodule_Exportorders/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Newmodule_Exportorders>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Newmodule_Exportorders>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportorders>
                <class>>Newmodule_Exportorders_Helper</class>
            </exportorders>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <exportorders>
                <class>>Newmodule_Exportorders_Block</class>
            </exportorders>
        </blocks>
        // Where is a model ?
        <models>
            <exportorders>
                <class>>Newmodule_Exportorders_Models</class>
            </exportorders> 
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Newmodule_Exportorders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Newmodule_Exportorders_Adminhtml</Newmodule_Exportorders>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <Newmodule_Exportorders_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>exportorders/observer</class>
                        <method>addMassAction</method>
                    </Newmodule_Exportorders_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Why should I declare the model? and it isn't working, I just tried it I got 404

Comment: The model for your observer, i changed the module name from ExportOrders to Exportorders and dont forget the app/etc/modules/Newmodule_Exportorders.xml

Comment: What's the point? Can you explain yourself?

Comment: Same thing by the way,'